# How to test android application in jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter, apk

How to test apk file application by using jmeter in mobile? I have already installed jmeter certificate and set the proxy, But when I open browser after starting recording then it works rather than I open any apk software then any record of http requests are not coming. Please help me to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take another step in order to make possible interception and decryption of the HTTPS traffic, see [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config):

- add the following line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)  section of your application manifest

  ```
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  ```
- create `network_security_config.xml` file under your application [resources folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and put the below code there

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
          <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
          <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
      </debug-overrides>
    </network-security-config>
  ```
- build your app in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
- replace the app in the device with the debug .apk from the previous step

Check out [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) guide for more details if needed